# Drupal 7: Filter view if date field has end date

Tags: date, drupal, view, filter, drupal-7

I have the following situation in Drupal 7: I have a content type "documents" which contains a field validity which is a Date field that is mandatory. It may contain an end date, but it also may not. (Single Date field that allows setting an end date.)

The meaning of this field is that if the end date is set, the document is valid only until this end date (which may be in the past or the future). If there is no end date set, the document is valid until further notice.

Now I want to create a view that filters all documents which are still valid. So the first filter I create is that the field_validity value is in the past. Now I need a filter that checks if either the end date is not set or is in the future. But in the database, the end date is set to the same date as the starting date, when it is not selected in the specific entity.

Any ideas how I can archive this?

Regards,
 Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a PHP views filter?  https://drupal.org/project/views_php
It allows you to create a Views filter which executes custom PHP code, so you can have full control over your condition.
The module only exists in a DEV version, but is widely used with 38,000 active installations.

Otherwise, if I understand correctly, you only want to show documents that are between field_validity and end date.

One option would be to problematically set your end date to something obscene (100 years later), if the value is blank.  This way your view will be simple to create.